# Data slicing evenly and odd using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Say, I have following data in dataframe

```
      a  
    -1043
    -1107
    -1110
    -1115
    -1193
    -1274
    -133
    -135
```

I want to select data even and odd and basis and put side by side in another variable. I want result something like this

```
           x          y
        -1043       -1107
        -1110       -1115
        -1193       -1274
        -133        -135
```

How to do this in a simple way using pandas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Just a `reshape`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['a'].values.reshape(-1,2), columns=['x','y'])
```

Output:

```
      x     y
0 -1043 -1107
1 -1110 -1115
2 -1193 -1274
3  -133  -135
```